# Bold for vectors, tensors, and matrices in mathematical formula (Springer journal)

Tags: fonts, equations, bold

I am preparing to send a paper to springer journal, In (instructions for Authors-> 
 Scientific style) there is an instruction said: Bold for vectors, tensors, and matrices. I used \bm to bold to do that:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\bm{P}_k^-}{dt}=\bm{F}_x(\bm{m}_k^-(t),t,\bm{\theta})\bm{P}_k^- +\bm{P}_k^- \bm{F}_x^T(\bm{m}_k^-(t),t,\bm{\theta}) + \Sigma(\bm{m}_k^-(t),t,\bm{\theta})
\label{eq:Euler}
\end{equation}
```

I get :

[image]

but in springer journal the equation looks like:
[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Also the derivative d's need to be upright, which is the only logical way to do it. But sadly Springer uses italic T's for transposed, which is inconsistent.

Comment: @lblb most mathematicians I know don't use straight d's, they look bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `mathbf` to produce the upright math fonts.

Since they usually represent vectors, you can renew the `\vec` command.

Also I created a derivative operator `\drv` which prints an upright `d` (as a derivative sign) keeping the spacing (at least to its right) that is present in the text

Here an implementation

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\drv\vec{P}_k^-}{\drv t}=\vec{F}_x(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\theta})\vec{P}_k^- +\vec{P}_k^- \vec{F}_x^T(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\theta}) + \Sigma(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\theta})
\label{eq:Euler}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to @GustavoMezzetti and @lblb for their insightful remarks

---

**EDIT**

Since the user asked, I provide a solution, which I don't know if optimal, concerning the bold math symbols.

The "normal" way in fact should be

1. Load `bm` and `upgreek`
2. Substitute the greek letter with its upshape, ie `theta` becomes `uptheta`
3. Call `\bm{\uptheta}` instead of `vec`

If one wants to keep the `vec` version, instead, has only to substitute theta with uptheta to obtain what he wants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,mathtools,upgreek}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\drv\vec{P}_k^-}{\drv t}=\vec{F}_x(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\uptheta})\vec{P}_k^- +\vec{P}_k^- \vec{F}_x^T(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\uptheta}) + \Sigma(\vec{m}_k^-(t),t,\vec{\uptheta})
\label{eq:Euler}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I beg to disagree with the `\ensuremath`: IMHO, a command like `\vec` should be used *only* in math mode, and rise an error if not.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Ok, I understand and I had doubts myself. I removed the `\ensuremath`

Comment: You'd have to use upright derivative d's too.

Comment: @lblb right. done

Comment: But, wait: I think that with `\drv(x^2)` (say) we are going to have a surpise…!

Comment: May I suggest, instead, `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I was going with `\newcommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` but ok

Comment: No, I guess making it robust is better (it could appear in a section title, for example).  Unfortunately, I cannot upvote again! :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Once is more than what deserved, thanks

Comment: why \vec{\theta} does not works?

Comment: @ Moriambar, \vec{\theta}  doesn't work for mathematical symbols.

Comment: @user137684 as for the upright greek letters, I'm quite unsure that the text uses the bold font, or simply the upright version. You should load the `upgreek` package, and substitute `theta` with `uptheta`

Comment: @user137684 I provide an edit to the answer, if you find using only the upright theta does not work